# How to pass the information to the controller and update properly to the DB

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Im using angularjs and ionic to build an app. In my view I have displayed a list of `fruits` and their `description`.When the user clicks on a specific fruit it will be re-directed to the another view `edit page`.In the `edit page` right now Im displaying the fruit's `id` from DB ,its `name` and `description` about it. where the `name` and `description` about the selected fruit can be edited. On moving the edited information to controller Im only able to see the values assigned to the `name` and  `description` but the id shows `null`,so how will I pass my `id` along with the other two information to controller so that it will get updated in the DB.

html:

```
 id:<div ng-model="mainId">{{selectInput._id}}</div>
            <hr>
        Selected Fruit:
      <div  contenteditable ng-model="editedName">{{selectInput.name}}</div>
          <br><hr>
       Decsription:
     <div contenteditable ng-model="fruit_desc">{{selectInput.descrptn}} 
     </div>
        <button ng-click="remove()">Delete</button>
    <button ng-click="Update()">Update</button></div>
```

controller:

```
  var updateName = $scope.editedName;
  var fruitId = $scope.mainId;
  var fruit_desc=$scope.description;
  var Updatepost = {'data':{'_id':fruitId ,'name': updateName, 'descrptn':description}};
   grocerystore.updatefruitList(Updatepost,function(err,response){
     console.log('able to access');
   });
   $state.go('app.mainList');
```

Comment: code is not enough to understand the issue.

Comment: actually I think the problem is in the ng-model binding so only i posted that part @Nikhil

Comment: first : `ng-model="fruit_desc"` mean that your description will be in `$scope.fruit_desc`. If this is not enough , provide more information

Comment: @Walfrat yes what you are saying is correct

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have `ng-model` in a `<div>`, please remove that.

Comment: if I declare <ng-model> will it work for id @Icycool

Comment: @sree no it won't. Just use `$scope.selectedInput._id` will do

Comment: @Icycool I tried but still the `id` shows undefined. Is there any other way.

Comment: How do you set the `selectInput`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127719/discussion-between-sree-and-icycool).